# check if column contains one of many values

Tags: sql

i have an array of strings and a column which may contain one or more of those strings(seperated by space) i want to get all rows where this column contains one of the strings. Since the values all have 3 letters and therefore can't contain each other, i know i could just write

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
column LIKE '%val1%' OR 
column LIKE '%val2%' OR 
column LIKE '%val3%' OR 
column LIKE '%val4%'
```

But i'm wondering if there isn't an easier statement, like `column IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')` (This one seems only to work when the entry is equal to one of the values, but not if it just contains them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Multiple LIKE Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975811/sql-multiple-like-statements)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: "*seperated by space*" might indicate a wrong database design and those strings should actually be converted to rows in a second table with a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql) and [Combining "LIKE" and "IN" for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server) , this will solve you question.

Something like this from the first link.

**SQL Server:**

```
WHERE CONTAINS(t.something, '"bla*" OR "foo*" OR "batz*"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ist oracle you could use regular expressions

```
select  * 
from    table 
where   regexp_like (column,'val(1|2|3|4)')
```